# java regex matching &[text]

Tags: java, regex

I am currently working on creating a regex to split out all occurrences of Strings that match the following format: &[*text*] and need to get at the *text*. Strings could look like: something &[*text*] &[*text*] anything &[*text*] etc.

I have tried the following regex but I cannot seem to get it to work: &\[(.*)\]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets are a bit tricky regarding escaping. Try this:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("&\\[([^\\]]*)\\]");
Matcher m = r.matcher("foo &[bla] [foo] &[blub]&[blab]");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
}
```

I replaced your dot with a group of any sign that is not a closing bracket. The star operator would otherwise greedily match until the very end of the string. You could also suppress the greedy matching with a question mark, this reads even better: `"&\\[(.*?)\\]"`

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do:

1. Double escape your square brackets
2. Prevent the capture group from matching other occurrences of the pattern, by preventing it from matching an opening or a closing bracket

> ```
> import java.util.regex.Matcher;
> import java.util.regex.Pattern;
>
> public class Test {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       String s = "&[test] something ] something &[test2]";
>       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]");
>       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
>       while (matcher.find()) {
>           System.out.println("capture group: " + matcher.group(1));
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Not sure if you need to prevent matching of an opening bracket. Something like `&[foo[bar]` could be a valid match.